# How to retrieve the nth element of a StringListProperty in AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to get the nth element in a String List Property in Appengine without using a for loop?

Something like nameOfList[2]

Thanks!

Comment: In a filter, or once you've retrieved the entity from the data store?

Answer (score 3):

These properties are lists, so all list methods apply. Try this on shell.appspot.com:

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import db
>>> class MyModel(db.Model):
  foo = db.StringListProperty()
>>> m = MyModel(foo=['bar', 'baz', 'ding'])
>>> m.foo[2]
'ding'
```

Comment: I must admit that I thought the OP would have tried what he suggested himself, hence my question. In retrospect, maybe not!

Comment: I tried, but somehow, it didn't work for me the first time :P I'll try again